# Can anyone identify this chip?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

This chip is from a Bobcat Miner 300. It's located somewhere next to the 12V input. IC has "AWKN *91" written on it where the star stands for an unreadable character.

It's a 6 Pin chip that looks like a Buck/Boost device or an amplifier.

[image: AWKN *91]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a Monolithic Power Systems [MP1658GTF](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp1658.html), however unfortunately the maker does not have a datasheet for confirmation on their website.

> MP1658 16V, 3A, 600kHz, High-Efficiency, Synchronous, Step-Down
> Converter In a SOT563 Package

AWK would be the product code, and N a year code.